# Trying to get an array from mysqli query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to get an array like this :

```
Array (
[0] => item1
[1] => item2
[2] => item3
)
```

But instead I'm getting an array like that :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => item1
        [column] => item1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => item2
        [column] => item2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => item3
        [column] => item3
    )
```

Here is my PHP code :

```
$my_array = array();

$my_query = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT column FROM `table`");

while ($row = $my_query->fetch_array()) {
$my_array[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); echo '</pre>';
```

Could you please help me to get an array organised like my first example ?

Comment: Use `while ($row = $my_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {`

Comment: Thank you, but then I have 
`[0] => Array ([0] => item1) [1] => Array ([1] => item2)  [2] => Array ([2] => item3)` and i would like `[0] => item1 [1] => item2  [2] => item3`

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention to your output requirement. Use `$my_array[] = $row[0];`